# Getting an access token for the Graph API works in a console app, but just hangs in a forms app

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, microsoft-graph-api

I can successfully get an access token for authenticating to the Graph API using a console application, however when trying to implement the same code using a Windows forms app, it just hangs on the line: `result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scope).ExecuteAsync();`

I've tried different ways than the below code, such as using the Microsoft Graph SDK which have again worked in a console app, resulting in the access code being in result.AccessToken which then enables me to be able to the calls to the Graph API, but `result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scope).ExecuteAsync();`just doesn't complete when used in a forms application.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace SimpleOnePagerConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        private static async Task RunAsync()
        {

            var clientId = "76a824c0-4dce-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
            var tenantId = "xxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
            var clientSecret = "B-0PWoQHPK1_-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            var scope = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            IConfidentialClientApplication app;


            app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                .Build();


            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            try
            {
                result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scope)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

I fully anticipate that there is something I am missing when it comes to Async/Await when using a forms application and I thank you for any help provided.

edit: Here is some code that hangs on the "ExecuteAsync()" I mentioned earlier.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace SimpleFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void getToken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            
        }
        public static async Task RunAsync()
        {

            var clientId = "76a824c0-4dce-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
            var tenantId = "xxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
            var clientSecret = "B-0PWoQHPK1_-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            var scope = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            IConfidentialClientApplication app;


            app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                .Build();


            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Getting Token");
                result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scope)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
                MessageBox.Show(result.AccessToken);

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ended up in catch block");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of posting your working code for the console application, post the code for your forms application which isn't working.

Comment: Amending my post with a quick forms app I put together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) 's MSDN article - [async-await best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) or his [blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), you are causing a deadlock in your code. You may benefit from reading his blog and MSDN articles I linked to above.

Event handler's are the 1 exception to the rule in `async/await`, you can mark the method `getToken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` as `async void`, so change to this and it will negate your deadlock issue:

```
private async void getToken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await RunAsync();
}
```

Also, if you are wanting to return the Token from your method, you may want to change to return a `Task<T>` where `T` is the object type of your token:

```
public static async Task<T> RunAsync()
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate, this worked perfectly. I will definitely go read the 2 articles you mentioned. I feel like I can now go amend my real application and start doing my Graph calls using a forms app. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: @Ashdmckenzie No problem. Glad I could help. I struggled with `async/await` and Stephen was kind enough to explain some of it to me. Just trying to pay it forward. Happy coding.